# How to access MongoDB document as JSONObject in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have documents like below in a collection named `event` in mongoDB

```
{
    "name": "pick",
    "message": {
        "word": "seven",
        "sequenceNumber": 34
    }
}
```

which existed before I developed my Spring Boot application to access it. 
Now I have a java object Event.java to access the above collection.

```
public class Event{
    private String name;
    private JSONObject messgae;
    // getters setters costructors
}
```

In the document, the `message` could be any json. So defining a class for `message` does not make any sense.
I have tried using `mongoOperations`, `mongoTemplate` and `mongoRepository` but I am not able to access the the document and change the value and store it again. The problems I face are,

1. I could not use `JSONObject` for message because `mongoOperations` has no support
2. I could not use `String` for `message` because when I save the object again it gets serialized like `"message":"{\"word ...`

Is there any way I can access, modify and store the data via spring boot application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSONObject` for message in `mongoOperations` like below.

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("word", "seven");
jsonObj.put("sequenceNumber", new Integer(34));

//save
Event eventDocument = new Event("pick",jsonObj);
mongoOperations.save(eventDocument);

//find
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("pick"));
Event object = (Event) mongoOperations.findOne(query, Event.class);
System.out.println(object.getName());
System.out.println(object.getMessage());
```

Comment: What's the full class name? is JSONObject from an external library?

Comment: org.json.JSONObject from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180130

Comment: Thanks, I did using json-simple, it worked like a charm